# Is this inductive big O proof possible / Does this question make sense?

Tags: induction, asymptotics

Prove that $\sum_{i=j}^k \frac 1i$ is $O(\ln(k)-\ln(j-1))$ using induction for all $i$.

The way I understand this question, it's nonsense - $i$ is the iteration variable, not something that can be inducted on.  I think it may be possible to do by induction on $j$ and $k$, but that's not "for all $i$".

Answer (score 2):

Hint: It is sufficient to know that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n{\frac{1}{i}}=\Theta(\ln n)$$

Answer (score 2):

And to complete
what Matt Samuel wrote,

Since
$\frac1{x}$
is a decreasing function,
and since
$(\ln(x))'
= \frac1{x}
$,
if $i \ge 2$,
$\frac1{i}
<\int_{i-1}^{i} \frac{dx}{x}
=\ln(i)-\ln(i-1)
< \frac1{i-1}
$ .

Summing from
$2$ to $k$,
since
$\sum_{i=2}^k (\ln(i)-\ln(i-1))
=\ln(k)
$,
$\sum_{i=2}^k \frac1{i}
< \ln(k)
< \sum_{i=2}^k \frac1{i-1}
$.

From the left side
$\sum_{i=1}^k \frac1{i}
< \ln(k)+1
$.

From the right side,
$\sum_{i=1}^k \frac1{i}
> \ln(k)+\frac1{k}
> \ln(k)
$.

These should be enough
to get what you want.

As is often the case for me,
nothing here is original.